# Excel Source SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have an SSIS package with an Excel Source reads an Excel table.  I currently am using the *Table or View* Data Access Mode and it is literally reading every row in the worksheet, `1,048,576` which is the maximum.

The source worksheet has an Excel table on it named `PSA_DATA`.  Why isn't this table in the *Table or View* drop down?  There is an option for the worksheet followed by `_FilterDatabase` but this fails when I run the package even though it pulls the correct data when I press Preview.  Wouldn't this make more sense than using the SQL Command and `SELECT * FROM [fact_PSA$Ax:Bx]`?  The whole reason we use Named Ranges and Tables in Excel is because they are dynamic!  Now I have to hard code the range in every time with rows numbers?

What am I missing here?  Is there an easier way I am missing?  I just want to move an Excel table into a SQL table!  Why don't doesn't the most ubiquitous piece of software in the world easily talk to the second most ubiquitous piece of software in the world!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

If the sheet name is not shown in Table or view combobox, it is not a bad idea to use a Sql Command.

But When using SQL Comand to read from excel it is not necessary to specify a range, OLEDB will take used range by default just use the following command

```
SELECT * FROM [fact_PSA$]
```

**Workaround**

you can try reading your excel file from a script task or a script component, you can follow one of the following links to achieve this:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2d45f180-9fd0-4224-a298-cb99e2b2100a/how-to-read-the-contents-of-excel-file-through-ssis-script-task-without-the-headers?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403358.aspx
- http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html

***Side Note:*** there are many links you can follow to import data from excel to SQL using SSIS:

- *http://www.sqlshack.com/using-ssis-packages-import-ms-excel-data-database/*
- *https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2770/importing-data-from-excel-using-ssis--part-1/*
- *https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/*
- *https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/*

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the links to work-arounds, but I didn't really get an answer to my question.  Why can't we reference an EXCEL TABLE (not a worksheet) from the SSIS Excel Source???

I ended up using the SQL Command data access mode with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [fact_PSA$A:W]
WHERE fact_PSA_ID IS NOT NULL
```

Somehow, using SQL stopped it from reading every possible row in the worksheet even though the range provided is set for "A:W" which is every row.  I guess the `"WHERE fact_PSA_ID"` limits the rows read before it hits the SSIS source.